# Determining whether a quadratic program is feasible

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Consider a system of constraints over non-negative variables $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ of the following form:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}=1$$
For every $i\in[n]$,
$$L_{i} \le x_{i} \le U_{i}$$
For every $(i,j)\in[n]\times[n]$,
$$L_{ij} \le x_{i} \cdot x_{j} \le U_{ij}$$

where $\{L_{i}\}_{i=1}^n$, $\{U_{i}\}_{i=1}^n$, $\{L_{ij}\}_{(i,j)\in[n] \times [n]}$, $\{U_{ij}\}_{(i,j)\in[n] \times [n]}$ are parameters in the range $[0,1]$.

I'm trying to find an algorithm that, given the set of parameters, decides whether or not the feasible region defined by the above system of constraints is empty. The algorithm doesn't actually need to find a feasible solution if one exists, only to determine its existence. While this program seems rather simple, I think it is not convex, so I guess Ellipsoid magic is not going to work.

Is there an algorithm, even super-polynomial, to decide whether the program is feasible?

Comment: $L_{ij} \leq x_ix_j$ can be made convex with a logarithmic transformation: $\log L_{ij} \leq \log(x_i) + \log(x_j)$.

Comment: @LinAlg, when applying this transformation I have to express all the constraints in the system in terms of the log of the variables. It is not clear to me how to express the first constraint (sum of all variables equals 1) in terms of logs.

Comment: you do not need to substitute $x'_i = \log(x_i)$. Such a substitution would make the constraint with $L_{ij}$ linear, but that is not necessary since it is good as-is (namely convex). The remaining problem is coping with $U_i$.

Comment: How large are the values of n that you are interested in?  Thousands? Millions?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, it can be assumed that the value of n is not very large (say, less than 100). I think I might have an exponential upper bound (still working on it), but I believe there should be a sub-exponential or maybe even polynomial solution to this problem.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what can be achieved by repeated interval-based bounds tightening. At each step, you can potentially try and improve $L_i$ and $U_i$ using $2n$ operations by using the information $\sum_{i} x_i = 1$. Next, using $2n^2$ operations, you can try to improve $L_{ij}$ and $U_{ij}$ by using the values of $L_i$ and $U_i$. You can iterate through this process to try and prove infeasibility or stop when you satisfy some maximum improvement criterion. I don't know if this procedure converges, but it might be interesting to experiment with it to try and establish feasibility

Comment: Since your instances are so small, asymptotic computational complexity simply isn't relevant.  Using an SDP relaxation of the rank-1 programming formulation of the problem within a branch and bound scheme would probably work well.